# Need Help Whitelisting IP Address Range - AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip, ip-address

I am struggling to understand the correct format for whitelisting IP address ranges to a database and webbapp hosted on an AWS EC2 instance.

For example, if this is a users given IP address: 23.283.149.136

How would I whitelist the users IP address range? I know IP addresses change subtle amounts.

Would it be 23.283.149.0/24? Or 23.283.149.0/32?

I ultimately ask the users for their work or home IP address to whitelist for the EC2 instance and have been having issues with their IP addresses changing.

Comment: IP addresses don't "change subtle amounts", if you want to whitelist 1.2.3.4, then you can whitelist 1.2.3.4/32.  If their ISP at either home or work assigns them a new IP, it could be from anywhere in their pool of IP addresses, which could have nothing at all to do with the previous IP they had.

Comment: I chose the term subtle because I noticed my work IP would change the last octet every other week. The first 3 octets would stay the same. So my thought was too allow any of the 256 numbers of the last octet access which seems possible through .0/24 or .0/32. Would you agree? @AnonCoward

Comment: Past one or two users, I'd expect you're going to be in for a world of management overhead if you go down this path of guessing what CIDRs to allow for each user.  Much better to allow all IPs, and filter out problem actors as they occur, or block all IPs and use something like [AWS SSM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/session-manager.html) to allow users to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get more information on which subnet they are on, and whitelist that entire subnet. In your example, whitelisting the CIDR `23.283.149.0/24` would allow the last octet of the IP address to change and they would still be able to connect. Here are a couple of use cases I have run in to in the past:

1. Whitelisting a home router IP address. This usually comes in the form of a Wide Area Network (WAN) IP address that is assigned to the home router and doesn't change. In this case, whitelisting a `/32` of that address should be fine. If they decide to move homes or internet providers, you will have to manually change the whitelist.
2. Corporate IP subnets. These can be wider for example `/24` to allow for wider ranges of subnets.

Where this gets untenable is if you have to accomodate remote users, for example someone who is a digital nomad and connects from coffee shop. In that case their IP address would change every day, sometimes multiple times a day, and would be impossible to manage.

As a result, many just allow `0.0.0.0/0` which is all IP addresses on ports 443 or 80, and place filters in front that block out known bad IP addresses. [AWS WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/) is one product that could be used to help with this.

Comment: Ok so in my case a lot of my colleagues work at universities. So those would most likely fall under the /24? And if a home address is given I can use /32?

Comment: I can't say, you would have to contact the University's IT department to get a list of IP subnets they use. Home addresses should be fine with /32 unless you're talking about managing thousands of homes, which would be too much overhead IMO.